# Creating cartesian product of sub-dictionary key-val pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, cartesian-product

I have this dictionary :

```
d = {
    'hosts': [{'hostname': 'ijk,uvw,xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.3,127.0.0.4,127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me,check-this,check-it'},{'hostname': 'abc,def', 'ip': '127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2, 'extra': 'check-for,check-this}]}
```

I want a dictionary with the cartesian product of the key-val pairs inside .

I need to create the below dictionary out of it:

```
d = {
    'hosts': [
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me'},
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-it'},
        {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-this'},
        {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra': 'check-for'},
        {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra': 'check-this'}
        {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra': 'check-for'},
        {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra': 'check-this'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't contain all possible combinations between the three fields because each hostname corresponds to exactly one IP. So it isn't actually a cartesian product.

Comment: My requirement is that only each hostnames should have the subsequent IP but the "extra" should be there in all the three hostnames and IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extracting all possible values, you can combine them using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
for host in d['hosts']:
    hostnames.extend(host['hostname'].split(','))
    ips.extend(host['ip'].split(','))
    extras.extend(host['extra'].split(','))

result = {'hosts': []}
for (hostname, ip, extra) in product(hostnames, ips, extras):
    result['hosts'].append({'hostname': hostname, 'ip': ip, 'extra': extra})
```

This produces a cartesian product which however means that you also get all combinations between hostnames and IPs. So you have to keep track of the hostname -> IP mapping:

```py
result = {'hosts': []}
for host in d['hosts']:
    hostnames = host['hostname'].split(',')
    ips = host['ip'].split(',')
    host2ip = {hostname: ip for hostname, ip in zip(hostnames, ips)}
    extras = host['extra'].split(',')

    for (hostname, extra) in product(hostnames, extras):
        result['hosts'].append({'hostname': hostname, 'ip': host2ip[hostname], 'extra': extra})
```

This gives

```
{'hosts': [{'extra': 'check-me', 'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3'},
           {'extra': 'check-this', 'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3'},
           {'extra': 'check-it', 'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3'},
           {'extra': 'check-me', 'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4'},
           {'extra': 'check-this', 'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4'},
           {'extra': 'check-it', 'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4'},
           {'extra': 'check-me', 'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5'},
           {'extra': 'check-this', 'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5'},
           {'extra': 'check-it', 'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5'},
           {'extra': 'check-for', 'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1'},
           {'extra': 'check-this', 'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1'},
           {'extra': 'check-for', 'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2'},
           {'extra': 'check-this', 'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2'}]}
```

Comment: The solution is correct but actually the hostname is taking a product of other dictionary's 'extra' in the list of dictionaries. I am editing my question a bit by providing the example. Please help on that.

Comment: @HardySandhu I've updated my answer

Comment: It worked thnx I am able to get required output @JanWilamowski

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
from itertools import product, chain


def f(d):
    t = product(zip(*(z := [d[k].split(',') for k in d])[:2]), z[2])
    return [dict(zip(d, (*x, y))) for x, y in t]

{'hosts': [*chain(*map(f, d['hosts']))]}
```

Ouput:

```
{'hosts': [{'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-me'},
           {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-this'},
           {'hostname': 'ijk', 'ip': '127.0.0.3', 'extra': 'check-it'},
           {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-me'},
           {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-this'},
           {'hostname': 'uvw', 'ip': '127.0.0.4', 'extra': 'check-it'},
           {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-me'},
           {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-this'},
           {'hostname': 'xyz', 'ip': '127.0.0.5', 'extra': 'check-it'},
           {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra': 'check-for'},
           {'hostname': 'abc', 'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'extra': 'check-this'},
           {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra': 'check-for'},
           {'hostname': 'def', 'ip': '127.0.0.2', 'extra': 'check-this'}]}
```

Comment: This is printing only 1 dictionary in the list of dictionaries. Am I doing something wrong here ?